# how we can define an instance which make new connection in socket.io?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, python-socketio, session.socket.io

we use  var abc = new WebSocket(url) to connect make new connection in websocket so in socket.io what we used to connect it or how can i do it please answer.

Answer (score 0):

How you connect a Socket.IO client to the server depends on each client. If you are using the JavaScript client on the browser you can do something like this:

```
socket = io();
```

Or if you need to connect to a 3rd party server:

```
socket = io('https://my.domain.com');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So can i use socket.on or socket.send event function using socket variable.